# How to get the trasaction that happens in 2020,2021 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, string, substring

I have a table with columns `id(int)` and `trans_id string`.

`trans_id` contains values such as `20345,19345` - the 1st 2 chars represent years, I want a query for transactions that happened in 2020,2019

Comment: Please fix the typos! And, while doing that, improve your question. (You can use [edit] to do that...)

Comment: Cruicially you should fix your design, combining multiple attributes in a single column is a serious antipattern, leading to poor performance (unsargable), confusion, errors, misreporting and unecessary overcomplication.

Comment: Review sqlserver string functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 particularly left and substring.

Answer (score 0):

You should store dates in a `date` or `datetime` column, not as a string or integer. And you certainly shouldn't store multiple values in one column.

Assuming `trans_id` is an `int` you can do

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE trans_id >= 19000 AND trans_id < 21000;
```

If `trans_id` is a `varchar` string, you can do

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE trans_id LIKE '20%' OR trans_id LIKE '19%';
```

If you've gone for an even worse version and stored multiple values, you need to split them first

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(trans_id, ',') s
    WHERE s.value LIKE '20%' OR s.value LIKE '19%'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `LEFT` to get the first two characters of the string.
Then use `IN` for the list of years you need.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE LEFT(trans_id, 2) IN ('19', '20')
```

But don't use `BETWEEN` without casting the 2 digits to an INT.